# Estou querendo fazer a exibição de um valor conforme a data atual

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quero selecionar o quantidade de `Num_CP` conforme a data atual, por isso estou usando a função `GETDATE()`, porém o meu SQL aponta o seguinte erro:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Meu Código:

```
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--DECLARE @DM3 DATETIME;

 SET @D0 = (SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE()) AS D0, COUNT(NUM_CP) AS QUANTIDADE_CPS FROM VW_Vendas);                        


 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, '-')'RESULTADO',
        (
        SELECT @D0 AS DATA_ATUAL FROM VW_Vendas VW0 WHERE VW0.SITUACAO_RECADO IS NOT NULL
        AND VW0.SITUACAO_RECADO LIKE '%Aguardando Aprovação Cliente%' AND
        VW0.DT_CRIACAO = GETDATE()
        )'DATAS DIA ZERO'


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Em tradução livre seu erro é o seguinte:

> Somente uma expressão pode ser especificada na lista de seleção quando a subconsulta não é introduzida com EXISTS.

Ou seja, você está buscando mais de uma expressão dentro de uma subconsulta. Para resolver esse problema você deve reescrever a primeira consulta para:

```
SET @D0 = (SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE())
             FROM VW_Vendas);
```

Ou:

```
SET @D0 = GETDATE();

SELECT @QUANTIDADE_CPS = COUNT(NUM_CP)
  FROM VW_Vendas;
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações na minha variável @QUANTIDADE_CPS, mas agora diz que o nome da minha coluna NUM_CP  é inválida. Então tentei utilizar o SELECT antes do count, e aponta que a sintaxe do meu select está errada.

Comment: @AnaClara agora que eu vi o que você está tentando fazer. Sugiro que você divida as responsabilidades. Vou alterar minha resposta

Comment: Fiz as alterações do jeito que você falou, mas por algum motivo, não funcionou, porquê o erro de somente uma expressão pode ser especificada voltou a aparecer.

Comment: @AnaClara talvez o erro esteja na sua view. Adicione o conteúdo dela na sua pergunta